# Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables to flow like regular two-column text

Tags: table-of-contents, two-column, front-matter

I found [this redefinition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26649/25730) of a table of contents very useful for my very long table of contents within my two-column book. With a slightly modified version of the command in the link, I got what I wanted:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\huge\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the same for `listoffigures` and `listoftables`. Does anyone know how?

I took a guess at what might do the job (below), but that definitely didn't work. If anyone can point me to documentation, that would also be appreciated. I know how to get rid of any undesired page breaks; that's not an issue.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\huge\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@startlof{lof}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[9pt,openany,twocolumn]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\huge\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\frontmatter
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Armadillo}
\section{Grubs}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Pink Fairy armadillo}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Beetle}
\section{Leaves}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Dung beetle}
  \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Cat}
\section{Birds}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Siamese cat}
  \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

I think I'm hungry??

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok. On the way...

Comment: The `\listoffigures` command has a `\listfigurename` command instead of `\contentsname`, likewise `\listoftables` with `\listtablename`

Comment: Isn't `\let\clearpage\relax` sufficient? Why do you want to redefine the commands?

Comment: I should have been clearer. By default, the table of contents or list of figures span both columns. I want them to flow along in two columns like regular text. Perhaps there is a really simple option for allowing this? I didn't know how to do it without redefining commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you have to use `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename` for the LoF and the LoT, respectively.

Also the command for generating them is `\@starttoc` in every case:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\huge\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\huge\listfigurename
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section*{\huge\listtablename
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\makeatother
```

MWE (`9pt` is not a valid option, minimum is 10):

```
\documentclass[openany,twocolumn]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\huge\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\huge\listfigurename
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section*{\huge\listtablename
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\frontmatter
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Armadillo}
\section{Grubs}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Pink Fairy armadillo}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Beetle}
\section{Leaves}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Dung beetle}
  \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Cat}
\section{Birds}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Siamese cat}
  \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

I think I'm hungry??

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks! I didn't know about the 10pt minimum. Thanks for informing me.