# How to customize list of tables?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, multicol, books

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{abcd}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    abcd
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{pqrs}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        pqrs
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\pagebreak
\begin{multicols}{2}
\listoftables
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This code provides the list of tables like this -
[image: multicol environment]

I want to use package `multicol`, but I don't want my second column to be above the title (i.e. List of Tables). I've no clue how to bring both of the columns at the same level. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redefine \listoftables to plot the header in a single column and then the list as twocolumn text. The solution to the MWE below is inspired by [a stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173177/redefining-listoffigures-and-listoftables-to-flow-like-regular-two-column-text)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \chapter*{\Huge\listtablename
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \end{multicols}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{abcd}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    abcd
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{pqrs}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        pqrs
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\pagebreak
\listoftables

\end{document}
```