# List of contentes and boxes. How to divide the page with many boxes for a report

Tags: box

I need a big hand. I'm trying to make a template for a report and the word file has many boxes on the first page. I managed to create the first boxes with a `\fbox` ambient and for the table of contents with a `\begin{frame}`. The problem is that the list begins on a new page while I want to a continuous text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pbox}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{{immagini/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.01cm,right=2.1cm,bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\headheight{33pt} %% just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo_ferrari.PNG}}
\chead{}
\rhead{\footnotesize\bfseries{\pbox[b]{\textwidth}{\color{gray}xxx\\ xxx}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox
to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule
height\headrulewidth\hfill}}
\rfoot{\thepage} %mette il numero pagina sulla destra del piede
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} %inserisce una line di divisione a piede pagina 
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox
to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height
\footrulewidth\hfill}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\footnotesize\bfseries{\pbox[b]{\textwidth
{\color{gray}xxx\\xxx }}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox
to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule
height\headrulewidth\hfill}} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox
to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height
\footrulewidth\hfill}} }
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth
\textbf{\underline{DIREZIONE xxx}\\ 
ENTE: TEc. xxx\\
AUTORE:    ....              \\
DATA:     ....  }            
\end{minipage}}
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.47\textwidth}
\textbf{
                        Report n. xxx\\ 
                        $\Box$ SIMULAZIONE
FLUIDODINAMICA \\
                        $\Box$ SIMULAZIONE \\
                        $\Box$ IMPOSTAZIONE}        
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.975\textwidth}
\textbf{\underline{OGGETTO}: Teoria delle vibrazioni}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.975\textwidth}
\textbf{
\underline{Descrizione attività}: Teoria delle xxxx}
\end{minipage}}
\begin{framed}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\end{framed}
Attività future:
\pagestyle{plain}
\input{xxx}
\input{xxx}
\input{xxx}
  \end{document}
```

If I use the `fobox` environment I have no problems until the text is longer than the page.

THANKS !!!!!!

Comment: Related .. possibly will work for you too. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26648/how-to-avoid-a-page-break-before-a-two-column-toc-in-memoir

Comment: great!!! It works!

Comment: Welcome... If this solved your problem, I suppose we can mark it as a duplicate... Should we?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right: the same preamble but after `\begin{document}`:

```
\begin{framed}
    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tableofcontents*
    \listoffigures
    \endgroup
\end{framed}`
```